# XML parsing code not working in chrome but works fine in Firefox and IE

Tags: xml, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I am trying to parse xml stored locally on systemit is working fine in Firefox as well as IE but when I am trying in chrome it is giving error:XMLHttpRequest cannot load file(path of file in desktop) Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.I tried to run chrome from cmd but still getting same error.

Code:

```
$( document ).delegate("#splash", "pageinit", function()

{   
$("#xmlvalue").click(function() {
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "third.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });

});

function xmlParser(data) {
        xml = data;
    $(xml).find('EMPLOYEE_DETAILS').each(function(){
   var srate = $(this).find('RATE_DISP_FLG').text();
   var sname = $(this).find('FULL_NAME').text();
   var orgid = $(this).find('ORGANIZATION_ID').text();
   var natid = $(this).find('NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER').text();
   $("<li></li>").html("RATE_DISP_FLG:"+srate +",FULL_NAME:"+  
   sname+","+orgid+",ORGANIZATION_ID"+",NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER"+natid)
  .appendTo("#dvContent");
  });

 }
    });
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Does Chrome have sufficient permission to access desktop/local file locations? Have you tried running Chrome as an administrator? Also are you using a relative or absolute path? An absolute path may pose a security concern as it will try resolve to the client's local machine rather than a physical path on the server.

Comment: @Le-roy for which are you saying absolute or relative path,how would O know that chrome has permission to access desktop/local file